# OpenSSL encryption method doesn't work on El Capitan

Tags: macos, terminal, encryption, openssl

The following file encryption method works on OS X Yosemite:

Encrypt: `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in file.zip -out file.zip.enc`

Decrypt: `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in file.zip.enc -out file.zip`

However, when on OS X El Capitan I get this error:

```
unknown option '-aes-256-cbc -in file.enc'
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have a shell quoting problem. The command works just fine for me in 10.11.4:

```
> which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl

> openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016

> openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in file.zip -out file.zip.enc; echo $?
enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:
Verifying - enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:
0

> openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in file.zip.enc -out file.zip; echo $?
enter aes-256-cbc decryption password:
0
```

Check to make sure that your calling program is treating `-aes-256-cbc` as a single option and isn't quoting it when sending it in to the shell. It looks like it's calling the program with option cluster `"-aes-256-cbc -in file.enc"` which actually isn't a valid, single option for `openssl`.

If you can provide more details about how you're calling `openssl` I can give you more specific guidance.

Comment: It worked. You are right. There is nothing inherently wrong with the method, except that my program was treating "-aes-256-cbc -in file.enc" as a single option for some unbeknown reason.

Thanks. Cheers. :)